# MongoDB big collection aggregation is slow

Tags: mongodb, performance, sorting, mongoose, search

I'm having a problem with the time of my mongoDB query, from a node backend using mongoose. i have a collection called people that has 10M records, and every record is queried from the backend and inserted from another part of the system that's written in c++ and needs to be very fast.
this is my mongoose schema:

```
{
    _id: {type: String, index: {unique: true}}, // We generate our own _id! Might it be related to the slowness?
    age: { type: Number },
    id_num: { type: String },
    friends: { type: Object }
}
schema.index({'id_num': 1}, { unique: true, collation: { locale: 'en_US', strength: 2 } })
schema.index({'age': 1})
schema.index({'id_num': 'text'});
```

Friends is an object looking like that: `{"Adam": true, "Eve": true... etc.}`.
there's no meaning to the value, and we use dictionaries to avoid duplicates fast on C++.
also, we didn't encounter a set/unique-list type of field in mongoDB.

**The Problem:**
We display people in a table with pagination. the table has abilities of sort, search, and select number of results.
At first, I queried all people and searched, sorted and paged it on the js. but when there are a lot of documents, It's turning problematic (memory problems).

The next thing i did was to try to fit those manipulations (searching, sorting & paging) on my query.

1. I used mongo's text search- but it not matches a partial word. is there any way to search a partial insensitive string? (I prefer not to use regex, to avoid unexpected problems)
2. I have to sort before paging, so I tried to use mongo sort. the problem is, that when the user wants to sort by "Friends", we want to return the people sorted by their number of friends (number of entries in the object).
   The only way i succeeded pulling it off was using `$addFields` in aggregation:
   `{$addFields: {$size: {$ifNull: [{$objectToArray: '$friends'}, [] ]}}}`
   this addition is taking forever! when sorting by friends, the query takes about 40s for 8M people, and without this part it takes less than a second.
3. I used `limit` and `skip` for pagination. it works ok, but we have to wait until the user requests the second page and make another very long query.

In the end, this is the the interesting code part:

```js
const { sortBy, sortDesc, search, page, itemsPerPage } = req.query
// Search never matches partial string
const match = search ? {$text: {$search: search}} : {}

const sortByInDB = ['age', 'id_num']
let sort = {$sort : {}}
const aggregate = [{$match: match}]

// if sortBy is on a simple type, we just use mongos sort
// else, we sortBy friends, and add a friends_count field. 
if(sortByInDB.includes(sortBy)){
    sort.$sort[sortBy] = sortDesc === 'true' ? -1 : 1
} else {
    sort.$sort[sortBy+'_count'] = sortDesc === 'true' ? -1 : 1

    // The problematic part of the query:
    aggregate.push({$addFields: {friends_count: {$size: {
        $ifNull: [{$objectToArray: '$friends'},[]]
    }}}})
}
const numItems =  parseInt(itemsPerPage)
const numPage = parseInt(page)
aggregate.push(sort, {$skip: (numPage - 1)*numItems}, {$limit: numItems})

// Takes a long time (when sorting by "friends")
let users = await User.aggregate(aggregate)
```

I tried indexing all simple fields, but the time is still too much.
The only other solution i could think of, is making mongo calculate a field "friends_count" every time a document is created or updated- but i have no idea how to do it, without slowing our c++ that writes to the DB.

Do you have any creative idea to help me? I'm lost, and I have to shorten the time drastically.
Thank you!

*P.S: some useful information- the C++ area is writing the people to the DB in a bulk once in a while. we can sync once in a while and mostly rely on the data to be true. So, if that gives any of you any idea for a performance boost, i'd love to hear it.*

Thanks!

Comment: Add explained query plans for all queries.

Comment: @D.SM Thank you, I added the code. let me know if you need anymore info